# Sed non greedy curly braces match

Tags: regex, sed, non-greedy

I have a string in a file a.txt

`{moslate}alho{/moslate}otra{moslate}a{/moslate}`

a need to get the string `otra` using sed.

With this regex

`sed 's|{moslate}.*{/moslate}||g' a.txt`

a get no output at all  but when i add a `?` to the regex

`s|{moslate}.*?{/moslate}||g a.txt`

(I've read somewhere that it makes the regex non-greedy) i get no match at all, i mean a get the following output

`{moslate}alho{/moslate}otra{moslate}a{/moslate}`

How can i get the required output using sed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SED doesn't support non-greedy matching, so you'll need to make the '.*' term less greedy by making it pickier in what it will accept. I don't have a corpus of the kind of things you're looking for, but I'm going to assume that you don't want to find anything with embedded curly brackets. If so, then you could use:

```
sed 's|{moslate}[^{]*{/moslate}||g' a.txt
```

which will work in the case you give, but will fail if these things nest.

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the string between *moslates* will not contain curly braces, you could do this:

```
sed 's/{moslate}[^{}]*{\/moslate}//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

"need to get" - Based on the context, it would seem that by "get" you mean "remove". However, I would normally interpret "get" to mean "retrieve" or "keep". What your `sed` command says is "delete everything". What would your desired output look like?

Assuming that you mean "retrieve" or "keep", try this:

```
sed -n 's|.*{/moslate}\([^{]*\){moslate}.*|\1|p' a.txt
```

which will retrieve "otra" or whatever is in the position that "otra" occupies in that string (i.e. between two sets of "moslate" tags).

The resulting output:

```
otra
```

If you want to remove "otra":

```
sed 's/otra//' a.txt
```

Output:

```
{moslate}alho{/moslate}{moslate}a{/moslate}
```

If you want to remove whatever is in the position that "otra" occupies in that string (i.e. between two sets of "moslate" tags):

```
sed -n 's|\(.*{/moslate}\)[^{]*\({moslate}.*\)|\1\2|p' a.txt
```

Output:

```
{moslate}alho{/moslate}{moslate}a{/moslate}
```